# Value not displaying when called by function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a card game.
The class is called `Card`:
It can give a random value with the `deal()` method to display a random card from the numbers 1-13
The other file will import the file name that contains the Class Card. It will call the class 5 times and be able to store it by appending it on a list and displaying it in another def called `display_hand`

Here is the class file:

```
import random


class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 0

    def deal(self):
        self.__value = random.randint(1, 13)

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.__value = value

    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

    def find_face_value(self):
        faces = ['Joker','Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six',
             'Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten','Jack','Queen','King']
        return faces[self.__value]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.find_face_value()
```

The program is too big so this is the def for calling the function 5 times:

```
def deal_hand():  



    # Create an empty list to append the cards.
    hand = []
    deal_hand = classcard3.Card()

    for i in range(5):

        #Deal the cards 


        # Creating an Object
        hands = deal_hand.deal()
# The cards show if I use print in here but is not showing
# whenever I use the function to display the values
        print('deal', deal_hand)
        # add it to the list
        hand.append(hands)

    return hand
```

Here is the display function:

```
def display_hand(hand):
    print ("The 5-card hand is: ")
    for item in hand:
        print(hand)
```

I don't get any errors, is just not showing anything except for the print inside the loop. How can I pass it to the display hand to show the cards?
This is the only thing that shows whenever I use the print function inside the loop. I'm trying to use it outside and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. My apologies if I'm not explaining this too well. I'm a beginner at python and new to this website. Thanks

```
deal Four
deal Three
deal Five
deal Six
deal Queen
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: In your last loop (in `display_hand`), probably mistake, you need to print `item` not `hand`

Comment: I switch the last end of it to `item` and is still not showing. My expected output is to display the 5 cards like I did in the loop. I just don't want to display it in the loop, I want to be able to store them display them in a different function.

Comment: Your final loop prints `hand` instead of `item`. `deal` should not be a method on card `Card`. A `deal` operation would be expected to take one card off the top of the remaining deck, which alerts us that there is no deck representation. `Card` should also take its suit and rank as part of its constructor/initializer, since it's invalid for a card to exist without these properties. Also, `Card` is a natural candidate for an immutable class; its rank and suit never need to change. `faces` should be converted to a global constant, rather than a local variable reconstructed on every call.

Comment: You also don't provide any code showing how `display_hand` is called, which means we have no idea what it's input is. From your description of the symptoms, it sounds like you're passing an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `hand.append(hands)` - you are adding `None` to the list.  `Card.deal()` doesn't return any value, it only modifies the `__value` attribute. But Python functions and methods always return `None`, if there is nothing else to return.

So when you do `hands = deal_hand.deal()`, you are assigning `None` to the variable `hands`, and then appending that value to the list `hand`. In the `deal_hand` function, the value is displayed using print, because you print the value of the `deal_hand` variable (which is an instance of `Card`), and not the `hands` variable.

Modifying the `deal_hand` function should solve the problem:

```
def deal_hand():  
    # Create an empty list to append the cards.
    hand = []

    for i in range(5):
        deal_hand = classcard3.Card()
        deal_hand.deal()

        print('deal', deal_hand)
        # add it to the list
        hand.append(deal_hand)

    return hand
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I still can't manage to show anything everything I execute it :\

Comment: I just tested it, and it works fine. You should do `display_hand(deal_hand())` to see the output.

Comment: That depends on where you want to actually display the hand. When you use `def`, you define a function. To actually run the function, you must call it, like `deal_hand()`.